# Merge lists of dictionaries by summing values of the same key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

How can I add multiple dictionaries in lists having name, value pairs such as:

```
dict1 = [{'name':'A','value':6}, {'name':'B', 'value':5}]

dict2 = [{'name':'A', 'value':10}, {'name':'C', 'value':12}]
```

Giving output as:

```
dict3 = [{'name':'A', 'value':16}, {'name':'B', 'value':5}, {'name':'C', 'value':12}]
```

Names in dictionary are not fixed and therefore random value in name field are possible.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931259/to-merge-two-dictionaries-of-list-in-python) is an example of how to merge two dictionaries into a list.

Comment: note that you are using a list of dictionaries `[{}, {}, ..., {}]`, and not a plain dictionary `{}`.

Comment: you can try reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931259/to-merge-two-dictionaries-of-list-in-python

Comment: @VictorEmilSimonsen @jonrsharpe, @TimH This is not a duplicate, because it is not a straight key-value dict, the key is mapped by `name` field and value by `value` field. All the suggested links are very different.

Comment: This post is asking about how to merge *multiple* dicts. The dupe target asks about how to merge 2 dictionaries specifically, ie not answering this question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this if you want to sum all values for unique `'name'` in each dictionaries :

```
names = set([k['name'] for k in dict1+dict2])
dict3 = []
for name in names:
    temp_val = []
    for dict_ in dict1+dict2:
        if dict_['name'] == name:
            temp_val.append(dict_['value'])
    dict3.append({'name': name, 'value' : sum(temp_val)})
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[{'name': 'A', 'value': 16}, {'name': 'B', 'value': 5}, {'name': 'C', 'value': 12}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
res = defaultdict(int)
for d in dict1+dict2:
    res[d['name']] += d['value']
[{'name': k, 'value':v} for k,v in res.items()]
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'B', 'value': 5},
 {'name': 'C', 'value': 12},
 {'name': 'A', 'value': 16}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a list of dictionaries with one key each, you can make that data structure much cleaner like so

```
dict1 = {'A' :6 , 'B' :5 }
dict2 = { 'A':10 , 'C' : 12 }
```

After that you can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to simplify the addition

```
from collections import Counter

dict1 = {'A' :6 , 'B' :5 }
dict2 = { 'A':10 , 'C' : 12 }

#Add the two counters and get the result
dict3 = Counter(dict1) + Counter(dict2)
print(dict(dict3))
```

The output will be

```
{'A': 16, 'B': 5, 'C': 12}
```

Comment: `dict1` and `dict2` are of list type in the question, not dict type.

Comment: Sure, let me update my answer to reflect that!