# Speed up fuzzy regex search Python

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy-search

I am looking for suggestions on how to speed up the process described below, which involves a fuzzy regex search.

##### What I am trying to do

I am fuzzy searching for `keywords`, stored in a dictionary `d` (with example just below, value is list of two always, need to keep track of which was found, if any), in a set of `strings`, stored in a file `testFile` (one string each line, ~150 characters each) - 4 mismatches max.

```
d = {"kw1": ["AGCTCGATGTATGGGTATATGATCTTGAC", "GTCAAGATCATATACCCATACATCGAGCT"], "kw2": ["GGTCAGGTCAGTACGGTACGATCGATTTCGA", "TCGAAATCGATCGTACCGTACTGACCTGACC"]} #simplified to just two keywords
```

##### How I do it

For this, I first compile my regex and store them in a dictionary `compd`. I then read the file line by line and search each keyword in each line (string). I cannot stop the search once a keyword has been found as multiple keywords may be found in one string/line but I can skip the second element in list associated with keyword if first is found.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import regex

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', help='file with strings')
args = parser.parse_args()

#dictionary with keywords
d = {"kw1": ["AGCTCGATGTATGGGTATATGATCTTGAC", "GTCAAGATCATATACCCATACATCGAGCT"],"kw2": ["GGTCAGGTCAGTACGGTACGATCGATTTCGA", "TCGAAATCGATCGTACCGTACTGACCTGACC"]}

#Compile regex (4 mismatches max)
compd = {"kw1": [], "kw2": []}  #to store regex
for k, v in d.items():  #for each keyword
    compd[k].append(regex.compile(r'(?b)(' + v[0] + '){s<=4}')) #compile 1st elt of list 
    compd[k].append(regex.compile(r'(?b)(' + v[1] + '){s<=4}')) #compile second

#Search keywords
with open(args.file) as f:  #open file with strings
    line = f.readline()  #first line/string
    while line:  #go through each line
        for k, v in compd.items():  #for each keyword (ID, regex)
            for val in [v[0], v[1]]:  #for each elt of list
                found = val.search(line)  #regex search
                if found != None:  #if match
                    print("Keyword " + k + " found as " + found[0]) #print match
                    if val == v[0]:   #if 1st elt of list
                        break   #don't search 2nd
        line = f.readline() #next line
```

I have tested the script using the `testFile`:

```
AGCTCGATGTATGGGTATATGATCTTGACAGAGAGA
GTCGTAGCTCGTATTCGATGGCTATTCGCTATATGCTAGCTAT
```

and get the following expected result:
`Keyword kw1 found as AGCTCGATGTATGGGTATATGATCTTGAC`

##### Efficiency

With current script, it takes about 3-4 minutes to process 500k strings and six keywords. There will be cases where I have 2 million strings, which should take 12-16 minutes and I would like to have this reduced, if possible.

Comment: Maybe have a look at bitwise operations i guess. Also what happens in the case: 

kw1:[a,b] and you find b. Do you skip a and still assign kw1 was found? Or is it always only the first in the list that will be found.

Comment: @JasonChia a or b can be found but it cannot be both. I will always start by looking for a (have to start somewhere) and if not found, will look for b. if b is found, kw1 should be marked as found. Will take a look at bitwise operations, thanks

Comment: @JasonChia Bitwise operations, you mean for example group a and b for each keyword so that I do only one search per keyword? I could but wondering how to keep track on whether it is a or b that was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a separate regex for each keyword requires running a match against each regex separately. Instead, combine all the regexes into one using the keywords as names for named groups:

```
patterns = []
for k, v in d.items():  #for each keyword
    patterns.append(f'(?P<{k}>{v[0]}|{v[1]})')
pattern = '(?b)(?:' + '|'.join(patterns) + '){s<=4}'
reSeqs = regex.compile(pattern)
```

With this, the program can check for which named group was matched in order to get the keyword. You can replace the loop over all the regexes in `compd` with loops over matches in a line (in case there is more than 1 match) and dictionary items in each match (which could be implemented as a comprehension):

```
for matched in reSeqs.finditer(line):
    try:
        keyword = [kw for kw, val in matched.groupdict().items() if val][0]
        # perform further processing of keyword
    except: # no match
        pass
```

(Note that you don't need to call `readline` on a file object to loop over lines; instead, you can loop over the file object directly: `for line in f:`.)

If you need further optimizations, have memory to burn and can sacrifice a little readability, also test whether replacing the loop over lines with a comprehension over matches is more performant:

```
with open(args.file) as f:
    contents = f.read() # slurp entire file
    matches = [{
          val:kw for kw, val in found.groupdict().items() if val
        } for found in reSeqs.finditer(contents)
      ]
```

This solution doesn't distinguish between repetitions of a given sequence; in particular, repetitions on a single line are lost. You could [merge entries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33931259/90527) having the same keys into lists, or, if repetitions should be treated as a single instance, you can merge the dictionaries as-is. If you want to distinguish separate instances of a matched sequence, include file position information in the keys:

```
matches = [{
      (val, found.span()):kw for kw, val in found.groupdict().items() if val
    } for found in reSeqs.finditer(contents)
  ]
```

To merge:

```
results = {}
for match in matches:
    results.update(match)
# or:
results = {k:v for d in matches for k,v in d.items()}
```

If memory is an issue, another option would be to break up the file into chunks ending on line breaks (either [line-based](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6335839/90527), or by reading blocks and separating partial lines at block ends) and use `finditer` on each chunk:

```
# implementation of `chunks` left as exercise
def file_chunks(path, size=2**12):
    with open(path) as file:
        yield from chunks(file, size=size)

results = {}
for block in file_chunks(args.file, size=2**20):
    for found in reSeqs.finditer(block):
        results.update({
          (val, found.span()):kw for kw, val in found.groupdict().items() if val
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I prefer using a line-by-line approach but getting one regex instead of 12 reduced the time by a minute (from 50s to 35s per 100k lines). I had to change the name of my keywords because there were dashes in them (didn't say in post) and could not use walrus operator := because I am on Python 3.7 but all else was fine!

Comment: @Agathe: I had missed the requirement to handle multiple matches in a single line; answer updated. Though it's not much of a change, it did remove the use of the walrus. As for the keyword format, it's probably better that's not in the question, as addressing it is a separate issue (and easily accomplished, which you did). I highly recommend [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) a few different implementations.